# trying to figure out why jsonp request does not work on form request

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I have two jsonp requests going to a 3rd party. My first attempt, https://jsfiddle.net/8k3f7b1v/13/ does not run. Console reads, 'cannot perform addEventListner on null'

I looked it over a few times and can't seem to figure out why it's breaking in that specific area. Why is the form null.

Here is a working version, https://jsfiddle.net/8k3f7b1v/12/ from someone else. Both forms use makeUrl with a query from searchField, yet I'm not understanding why this works and not the other one.

HTML

```
<form id="search-container-form">
 <label for="search">Search <input id="search" type="text"></label>
 <input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
<h1>
 Output
</h1>
<div id="output">
</div>

//non working fiddle JS

var form = document.getElementById('search-container-form')
var searchField

function defaultUrl() {
 return 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=mario&callback=appendResults'
}

function makeUrl(query) {
 return `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=${query}&callback=appendResults`
}

function getJSON(url) {
 var script = document.createElement('script')
 script.src = defaultUrl()

 script.onload = function() {
  this.remove()
}

 var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
 head.insertBefore(script, null)
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault()

 var searchField = document.getElementById('search').value
 getJSON(makeUrl(searchField))
})

getJSON(defaultUrl())

window.appendResults = function(data) {
 console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: second fiddle is also throwing error

Comment: Both fiddles have the same URL. `document.getElementById('search-container-form')` will return `null` in the fiddle because there is no element with that ID; there are no elements at all...

Comment: Form is defined in the HTML. See the edited post.

Comment: second version should now work with updated link.